# Python for Windows Extensions - what does it do?

Tags: python

Can someone explain what this library does? Apparently, one of the things it does is allow automatic detection of SDKs. No, they don't mention what it does on their [website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) :-(.

Comment: for documentation check out http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/PyWin32.HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can find many examples of use of win32com and other win32 packages in [here](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/category/7/87/189/).
In addition, Tim Golden's [win32 How do I](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i.html)? and [Mike Driscoll blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/category/windows/) are very rich sources for win32 examples.

If you install [Activepython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) you get win32all/pywin bundled and with a collection of docs on the package.

With ActivePython you also get a shell/IDE with tools to inspect and work with com objects

Comment: Thanks, the examples were just what I needed to understand why it is useful

Comment: Please, note that there was an error in one of the urls so that the link 'here' was no accesible. Now is corrected.

Answer (score 8):

It provides Python bindings for the Win32 API and for COM.